# Use sendmail as client for relaying mail

Tags: sendmail, email, smtp, smarthost

I'm trying to use an account on my central mail server to send all mails from other boxes. My central mailserver is itracknetworks.ca and I have an account there at testuser@itracknetworks.ca. I currently have the following in sendmail.mc

```
[root@localhost mail]# cat sendmail.mc | grep -v "^dnl"
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl

define(`SMART_HOST', `mail.itracknetworks.ca')

define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=25')
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=26')
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
MASQUERADE_AS(`itracknetworks.ca')dnl
FEATURE(masquerade_envelope)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
```

Plus I have the following in my /etc/mail/access

```
AuthInfo:mail.itracknetworks.ca "U:faxes@itracknetworks.ca" "I:testuser@itracknetworks.ca" "P:*****" "M:LOGIN PLAIN"
```

But when I send the mail, I can see that it's still going from localhost.localdomain. I have read that SMART_HOST is only used if all other methods of delivery fail. So, how do I ensure that *all* mail goes through the account described in /etc/mail/access?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your configuration down to following

```
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
FEATURE(`nullclient',`mail.itracknetworks.ca').
```

Excerpt from [documentation](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/features.html)

> nullclient
>
> This is a special case -- it creates a configuration file containing nothing but support for forwarding all mail to a central hub via a local SMTP-based network. The argument is the name of that hub.
>
> The only other feature that should be used in conjunction with this one is FEATURE(`nocanonify'). No mailers should be defined. No aliasing or forwarding is done.